# i need java code to open html code onclick event

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have banner HTML code if people goes to click on a text, the click should open my banner HTML page. I need a clickable text to open my HTML page. Below is my banner HTML page, i need clickable text for below banner HTML. so i need java code to open below html page on click event.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adhitzads.com/787096"></script>
```

Comment: you can embed this text into a tag

Comment: could you please tell me brief

Comment: please share some piece of code then i will tell you how to use it

Comment: this is my another banner ad.. <p align="center"><a target="_blank" href="http://buildmydownlines.com/?s=27324">

    <img border="0" src="http://buildmydownlines.com/images/468x60getpaid.gif" align="center" width="468" height="60" alt="Get Paid To Join Websites"></a></p>

Comment: please anyone help me to get clickable text for html banner code

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="div">TEXT</div>
```

javascript

```
$("#div").click(function () {
    window.location.href="https://www.google.com";
});
```

and include any latest jquery...you can use

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: that is html code.. i need clickable text for that code.. if someone clicks on text that html page should open

Comment: you can redirect your html page on click event of text id

Comment: i think u are talking about javascript not java